# Crashed rootserver, problems getting typo3 up and running from backups, now db problems (mariadb)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Due to a libc mismatch (or the like) while dist-upgrading an older Debian server I had to re-install it completely. I choose Debian bookworm, and installed Apache (2.4.57-2) along with MariaDB (1:10.11.3-1). I had in mind to update Typo3 to a current version later, but I thought it would be better to get the old Typo3 version up and running first (6.2.30, by the way), and then update Typo3 to successively higher version later. As I did not expect to get an old Typo3 running using PHP 8.2 I installed PHP 5.6 from the Sury repository. Importing the databases went smoothly; just copied the binary files (to /var/lib/mysql etc.), and after running mariadb-upgrade (if I remember correctly) the databases were up and running. Access to DB via socket and port (3306/mysqld.sock) no problem so far.

Well, Typo3 now throws an error "Oops, an error occurred!", [sitename]/typo3 along with [sitename]/typo3/sysext/install/Start/Install.php (which I also tried, having file backups I thought why not) both yield (sorry, that's long):

```
Oops, an error occurred!

It looks like the character set utf8 is not used for this connection even though it is configured as connection  charset. This TYPO3 installation is using the  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['setDBinit'] property with the  following value: "". Please make sure that this command does not  overwrite the configured charset. Please note that for the TYPO3  database everything other than utf8 is unsupported since version 4.7.
```

I tried, of course, to find something in the 'net about that error messages, but I am a bit overwhelmed from a lot of results about Typo3 versions either too old (like 4.5, [text](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/41596)) or too new, eg. [text](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85524), or (perhaps more fitting) [text](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/typo3db_legacy/issues/16). As I strongly suspected an utf8/utf8mb4 mismatch (as Debian installs MariaDB using UTF8MB4, as far I I know), I inserted 'charset' => 'utf8mb4' to LocalConfiguration.php, but it did not change anything.

Now I am unsure what to do, and so I thought it would be perhaps better to ask for some help. And, well, I'm not a DB person. I noticed most Typo3 mailing lists seem to be dead, but I found a hint (in typo3_src-12.4.6/README.md, just got the sources, didn't do anything with V12) about stackoverflow, so I came here. As you perhaps see my Typo3 days are some years past, too, so I'd be very grateful for some hints how to go on:).

Edit: I forgot one thing… the "Oops" error page mentioned above also has a link at "More information regarding this error might be available online.", this leads to https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1389697515.html [Exception 1389697515](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1389697515.html), which did not yield me much of a clue.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 6.2 was using MySQL 5.1 at the time. More recent versions of that, or newer MariaDBs will
probably yield all sorts of issues. This is only the tip of the iceberg, like you found out, utf8 instead of utf8mb4 is needed for this old TYPO3.

How complex was your installation? It would probably be easiest if you install a fresh TYPO3v12 and try to import your content (pages&tt_content) there, but that can be a huge task depending on how many and which extensions you used, if multidomain/multilanguge/workspaces etc were involved etc...

(Another option: try to instead setup a mysql 5.1 server, on another port or so - or mariadb 5.1. Try to import an SQL dump, not a binary, from your currenr install)

HTH - this will not be an easy task.

Comment: First, let me thank you for the comment! I am currently trying to get the file backup running within a virtual machine (old mysql as well), so I have a chance to get the old Typo3 (6.2) running as well, and then maybe export as much as I can as .t3d files.  Fortunately I also have mysql SQL dumps as well, as I had a cron job exporting them on the old server.  Anyway, if someone has a hint how to overcome that (suspected) utf8/utf8mn4 mismatch, I would be grateful - I have the nagging feeling that this is just a little obstacle but too high for me, perhaps.  Anyway, I will report how it went.

Comment: Alright, thanks for dropping back with an update. My feeling is you'll probably not get along with utf8mb4, but would need to utilize utf8 only. Let me know kf your progress. :-)

Comment: In any case I'll write how it went; I really hate having a problem and searching the 'net for it, just to find someone somewhere having the same problem who found a solution only to write 'thanks, works now' (or nothing at all) only to be never been seen again.    Anyway, after some fiddling, now I have a VM up and running resembling the old server where everything works, incl. T3. So next step's exporting and test-importing to a T3v12 in a Debian/bookworm VM. And it's very soothing to have the sites running somewhere, even if in a VM. Opens up more possibilities too, eg. t3d etc.