# t3d file import error: "htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given"

Tags: typo3

In the wake of another problems due to a [rootserver crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247469/crashed-rootserver-problems-getting-typo3-up-and-running-from-backups-now-db-p) I managed to get a file backup up and running in a virtual machine along with the old Typo3 installation (6.2.30). This gave me the possibility to export the old site to a .t3d file. In another VM (nearly identical to the 'new' server) I got Typo3 (12.4.6) running to have a 'test stage'. By the way, T3v12 look very nice and clean, compliments.

But importing the .t3d file yields an error message in the backend: "htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given". Checking the Typo3 logfile yields first two warnings:

```
Sun, 08 Oct 2023 18:27:27 +0000 [WARNING] request="418b1cee8d80d" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ErrorHandler": Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Undefined array key "8e79286a8efa8a13de373312028aee83" in /srv/www/typo3_src-12.4.6/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php line 721
Sun, 08 Oct 2023 18:27:27 +0000 [WARNING] request="418b1cee8d80d" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ErrorHandler": Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /srv/www/typo3_src-12.4.6/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php line 738
```

… then an error message:

```
Sun, 08 Oct 2023 18:27:27 +0000 [CRITICAL] request="418b1cee8d80d" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): TypeError, code #0, file /srv/www/typo3_src-12.4.6/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php, line 738: htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"TypeError","exception_code":0,"file":"/srv/www/typo3_src-12.4.6/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php","line":738,"message":"htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given","request_url":"http://[sitename.tld]/typo3/record/importexport/import?token=--AnonymizedToken--","exception":null}
```

… which is, of course, the reason for the backend error message.

Line 738 would be "$line['title'] = htmlspecialchars($fileInfo['filename']);". This looks awfully like a patch message I fould, [Bugfix v11](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/97658) with [Patch](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/74770) for v11.5. Looking at that patch  [diff](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/74817/2/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php) it seems to me that, perhaps, at that line 738 `$line['title'] = htmlspecialchars($fileInfo['filename']);` just "?? '"'s missing. I tried that, but that just throws the next error at line 747 (or like that), so I gave up for the time being. And unfortunately my PHP skills are nonexistent.

So, what would be the best thing to do? v12's "recommended for new projects" and designed as "stable", but would it be wise to use v11 for now and update in eg. half a year or such?

As usual I'm grateful for any hint:).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the T3D format changed a bit, yielding these errors.

The patches you found are also contained in v12, so using v11 probably will not work either. I'd suggest that we try to patch up v12 and your t3dd to get there.

How "private" is your t3d file? If you would be able to share it, I could offer to inspect it and see if it can be easily salvaged somehow...?

Do you know #slack? You could join typo3.slack.com to make it easier to work synchronously on your issue (and share files). Hit me up there, in case you want to take up the offer. :-)

We should document the findings here afterwards of course.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd really like that!  The t3d file is not private at all, here it is: [link](http://kartan.de/kartanexport.t3d) And of course I'll help write findings, so others may benefit too. I'll gladly join typo@slack tomorrow (am very tired right now). Thanks again!

Comment: I was able to fix 2-3 bugs and import your T3D. Will report back tomorrow and prepare a patch for you.

Comment: That's really good news! Btw., I have deleted the t3d file, that's ok? If needed I can put it up again. And - many thanks!

Comment: Yes I downloaded it. BTW: You should create the t3d file and NOT export sys_log or sys_history DB tables; those are very big and just increase the dump size immensively.

Could you check out this patch: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/81389 - can you "read" this and try to apply it to your instance to see if it works for you? I hope the patch gets accepted for an upcoming TYPO3v12 version.

Comment: I'll keep in mind to not export these tables - I have to admit I have never exported t3ds before. And yes, I can read patches without problems (well, at least most of the time:). And there's even a file download (right side), good for lazy ole me, not even having to use diffs! Have applied the patches and will test in 10 minutes…

Comment: Got another error: "Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Class "TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconSize" not found | Error thrown in file /srv/www/typo3_src-12.4.6/typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/ImportExport.php in line 535. Requested URL: http://[site]/typo3/record/importexport/import?token=--AnonymizedToken--" - line 535 is "(array)($this->dat['records'][$table . ':' . $uid]['data'] ?? []), IconSize::SMALL". I have the nagging feeling I forgot something like installing an extension (but it's core, right?) or some php stuff (but shouldn't then the installer do not pass?).

Comment: Perhaps I forgot in important information: I have downloaded and used the "classic way" .tar.gz package, not the composer stuff, so perhaps something's missing in there. And I forgot to thank you for your work! Methinks the patches will be accepted, but surely you already know:).

Comment: The file is feom TYPO3v13, you cannot use it directly. Thats why I asked if you can read the patch ;) Could you try to apply it to your original file?

Comment: Well, those who can read are clearly at an advantage - was dead tired last night. Of course you're right; I will apply the patch directly & by hand when I'm back from work.